# How do I execute xshell?

Tags: 14.04

I download xshell.exe file and i try to excute it using terminal by typing `./xshell.exe`
But I can't excute it.
How can I do it?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Exe files are executable files for Windows, not for linux.

You can not just run them in Ubuntu.

Some of Windows executable files can be run using wine.

You can install it by

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

and try to open them by right-clicking and selecting "wine".

But I see no reason of using xshell in Ubuntu. You can use Ubuntu terminal with ssh client for all you need.